# How to decrease the gap between tree nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees, forest

is there an option to decrease the gap (red circle) between nodes 3dots and "Transmission Zone-k"? I want "3dots" node in the middle of nodes "Transmission Zone-2" and "Transmission Zone-k".

My code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{col1in}{red!30}
\colorlet{col1out}{red!40}
\colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40}
\colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50}
\colorlet{col3in}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col3out}{blue!40}
\colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20}
\colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30}
\colorlet{col5in}{blue!10}
\colorlet{col5out}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6in}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6out}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col7out}{orange}
\colorlet{col7in}{orange!50}
\colorlet{col8out}{orange!40}
\colorlet{col8in}{orange!20}
\colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
  rect/.append style   = {rectangle, rounded corners = 2pt,
                         inner color = col6in, outer color = col6out},
  ellip/.append style  = {ellipse, inner color = col5in,
                          outer color = col5out},
  orect/.append style  = {rect, font = \sffamily\bfseries\LARGE,
                         text width = 325pt, text centered,
                         minimum height = 10pt, outer color = col7out,
                         inner color=col7in},
  oellip/.append style = {ellip, inner color = col8in, outer color = col8out,
                          font = \sffamily\bfseries\large, text centered}}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
      line width=1pt,
      draw=linecol,
      ellip,
      align=center,
      parent anchor=south,
      l sep+=15pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      inner sep=5pt,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[color=linecol,
          >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, -, \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -|
          (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      where level={3}{tier=tier3}{},
{},
  }
  [Interconnection,rect, inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out
    [Transmission\\Zone-1,rect, inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out
      [UPV$_1$, rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
      [$\cdots$, rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
      [UPV$_l$, rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
    ]
    [Transmission\\Zone-2, rect, inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out
      [UPV$_1$, rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out
        [Inverter-1, rect, inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
        [$\cdots$, rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
        [Inverter-y, rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
      ]
      [$\cdots$, rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
      [UPV$_m$, rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
    ]
    [$\hspace{10pt}\cdots\hspace{10pt}$, rect,inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out]
    [Transmission\\Zone-k, rect, inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out
    [Distribution\\Node,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out
    [DPV$_1$,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out
    [Inverter-1,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
    [$\cdots$,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
    [Inverter-z,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]]
    [$\cdots$,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
    [DPV$_v$,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]]
    [UPV$_1$,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
    [$\cdots$,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]
    [UPV$_n$,rect,inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The figure:
[image: gap]

Comment: Maybe try "sibling distance" section 21.5.2 Default Growth Function of the tikz manual

Comment: Please, also give us a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: working example is added.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it is rather impolite not to acknowledge the source of code you've adopted from somebody else's work. In this case, you would also be wise to prune that code: if you don't want orange ellipses, why include a definition for that style? I can't add the attribution because I would have to search down the source and I can't even remember if it is mine or if I've just worked with MWEs based on it so many times it now feels familiar.

Here I've also updated the code for current Forest, which makes this kind of tree a lot more straightforward. If I knew the source of the code, I could update that, too, but I don't, so I can't.

```
% addaswyd o gôd o gwestiwn Reiso: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408737/ - ond yn wreiddiol gan rhywun arall, 'dw i'n sicr
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40}
\colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50}
\colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20}
\colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30}
\colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
  rect/.append style   = {rectangle, rounded corners = 2pt, inner color = col4in, outer color = col4out},
}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    line width=1pt,
    draw=linecol,
    align=center,
    parent anchor=children,
    l sep+=15pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
    inner sep=5pt,
    edge+={color=linecol, line width=1pt},
    fork sep'=10pt,
    where level={3}{tier=tier3}{},
    rect,
  },
  where level<=1{inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out}{},
  [Interconnection
    [Transmission\\Zone-1
      [UPV$_1$]
      [$\cdots$]
      [UPV$_l$]
    ]
    [Transmission\\Zone-2
      [UPV$_1$
        [Inverter-1]
        [$\cdots$]
        [Inverter-y]
      ]
      [$\cdots$]
      [UPV$_m$]
    ]
    [$\hspace{10pt}\cdots\hspace{10pt}$,
      before drawing tree={
        x/.average={x}{p,fake=n,n}
      }
    ]
    [Transmission\\Zone-k
    [Distribution\\Node
    [DPV$_1$
    [Inverter-1]
    [$\cdots$]
    [Inverter-z]]
    [$\cdots$]
    [DPV$_v$]]
    [UPV$_1$]
    [$\cdots$]
    [UPV$_n$]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: node centred between siblings]

Note that this will only work if there is space. If not, you'll end up with overlapping nodes.